# How can I ignore OCI_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO Exception

Tags: php, oracle, pdo, oracle-call-interface

I'm trying to connect to an Oracle server using following code:

```
try{
    $pdo = new PDO("oci:dbname=" . $tns . ";charset=utf8", $user, $password);
} catch (\Exception $e){}
```

But it throws me an exception like:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: OCISessionBegin: OCI_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO: ORA-28011: the account will expire soon; change your password now (/root/php-5.4.35/ext/pdo_oci/oci_driver.c:686)

Please anybody tell me, how can I ignore it, without changing the pass.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you can't change the password?

Comment: Besides, you'd better change it. Once it expires, you might find yourself *locked*, and that's something you won't just *ignore*.

Comment: The way to ignore it is to ... ignore it and keep using `$pdo`.  But the advice of @Littlefoot should be heeded and you may need a DBA to reset your password.  (If you were using PHP OCI8 you could connect and change an expired password)